# Trying to set a column as email sent so I dont keep resending emails again and again

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have a request form, need to send email to the requesters once done, only thing is it keeps resending to the entire list. I want to restrict and send only to those who haven't been emailed before so need to add "Email Sent" in a new column. But its not working. Can someone help

```html
function sendEmails() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:E6");
  const data = dataRange.getValues();
  

  data.forEach(function (rowData) {
    const recipient = rowData[0];
    const emailAddress = rowData[2];
    const status = rowData[3];
    const done = rowData[4];
    
  

    if (status !== 'approved') {
      return
    }

    const greeting = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n'
    const statusMessage = 'Your request is  ' + status ;
    const greatJobMessage = 'Thanks for playing! :)';

    const message = [greeting, statusMessage, greatJobMessage].join('\n');
    const subject = 'Request '+ status;

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    done.setValue('sent')
  
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:E6");
  const data = dataRange.getValues();
  const rangeList = data.reduce(function (ar, [recipient, , emailAddress, status, done], i) {
    if (status == 'approved' && done != 'sent') {
      const greeting = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n'
      const statusMessage = 'Your request is  ' + status;
      const greatJobMessage = 'Thanks for playing! :)';
      const message = [greeting, statusMessage, greatJobMessage].join('\n');
      const subject = 'Request ' + status;
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      ar.push("E" + (i + 2));
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (rangeList.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue('sent');
  }
}
```

- In this modification, when the values of columns "D" and "E" are `approved` and not `sent`, an email is sent. And, when the email was sent, `sent` is put to the column "E". For this, I used the rangeList. By this, a value can be put to the split cells.

#### References:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
- [setValue(value) of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setValue(Object))
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> Works for this sheet but I need to set columns for email, Status etc at will because my form is long then 26 columns and will keep changing

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  // Please modify the colum numbers of the following variables for your actual situation.
  const recipientCol = 1; // This is the column A
  const emailAddressCol = 3; // This is the column C
  const statusCol = 4; // This is the column D
  const doneCol = 5; // This is the column E

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:E6");
  const data = dataRange.getValues();
  const rangeList = data.reduce(function (ar, r, i) {
    const recipient = r[recipientCol - 1];
    const emailAddress = r[emailAddressCol - 1];
    const status = r[statusCol - 1];
    const done = r[doneCol - 1];
    if (status == 'approved' && done != 'sent') {
      const greeting = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n'
      const statusMessage = 'Your request is  ' + status;
      const greatJobMessage = 'Thanks for playing! :)';
      const message = [greeting, statusMessage, greatJobMessage].join('\n');
      const subject = 'Request ' + status;
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      ar.push("E" + (i + 2));
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (rangeList.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue('sent');
  }
}
```

Comment: Works for this sheet but I need to set columns for email, Status etc at will because my form is long then 26 columns and will keep changing

Comment: @user2389019 Thank you for replying. From `Works for this sheet`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `but I need to set columns for email, Status etc at will because my form is long then 26 columns and will keep changing`, I couldn't notice about this. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. For your replying, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi Thanks for Updating but the changed script isn't working.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GAYAs4fPdmBD3NgWhWAIKwZ3oF6IpJQuIAcDzW0YQJ0/edit?usp=sharing
Here is the spreadsheet

Comment: @user2389019 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your current issue from `but the changed script isn't working.`. Can you provide the detail of your current issue?

Comment: @user2389019 And in your sample Spreadsheet, please modify the variables of `recipientCol`, `emailAddressCol`, `statusCol`, `doneCol` for your actual situation. Because I cannot understand what columns do you want to use. And also, in your sample Spreadsheet, my proposed script is not included. So I cannot understand your current situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill. By correctly understand your current issue, I would like to think of the modification points. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: B, = recipientCol, E=emailAddress,Y=status, AA = Done.
Working perfectly now Thank you. Except Sent is getting updated in the email column. Your english is great btw